# getting error like unhadler (kernelbase.dll) openCV using C++

Tags: opencv

I am doing simple program to detect webcam, it runs for some time but than I am getting the error message.
i took the code from,

https://thefreecoder.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/opencv-c-video-capture/

> Unhandled exception at 0x74f22f71 (KernelBase.dll) in cvtest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0109f524..

how to solve this problem.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: aaah the good old `0x0109f524 exception`. the code looks good so far so it could be anything. maybe you could trace down on wich line the problem occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the entire code within the try catch block

```
try
{
   // ... Contents of your main
}
catch ( cv::Exception & e )
{
  cout << e.msg() << endl;
}
```

This might help you! or Try with the debugger which line cause the exception.

Comment: here is my code,#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
VideoCapture stream1(0);   //0 is the id of video device.0 if you have only one camera.
stream1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
stream1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
if (!stream1.isOpened()) { //check if video device has been initialised
cout << "cannot open camera";
}
 
//unconditional loop
while (true) {
Mat cameraFrame;
stream1.read(cameraFrame);
imshow("cam", cameraFrame);
Mat roi = cameraFrame( Rect(150,50,150,250) );
imshow("cam1",roi);

if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
break;
}
return 0;
}

Comment: still facing same problem, its work some time fine without any error and some time its give me error.

Comment: Try this link. Replace cap("VideoPath") by cap(0)//0 is your camera id.                                                                                               http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2011/09/capturing-images-videos.html